# The right way to perform a task asynchronously in Django, via Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Django app which mimics Instagram, in that users upload photos or memes, and then their fans get notified of the said photo.

Currently, in order to send notifications, as soon as a user uploads a photo, I iterate through every fan the uploader has, append the notifications to a list, and then `bulk_create` the objects. As in:

```
    fans = UserFan.objects.filter(star=user).values_list('fan',flat=True)
    fan_list = []
    for fan in fans:
        fan_list.append(PhotoObjectSubscription(viewer_id=fan, which_photo=photo, updated_at=time, seen=False, type_of_object='1'))
    PhotoObjectSubscription.objects.bulk_create(fan_list)
```

Simple stuff. Note that I also have `supervisord` installed on my app's VM, where I run some rudimentary tasks via `celery` (with `redis` as message broker).

Now I want to perform the `bulk_create` task above as a `celery task`; asynchronously. My `bulk_create` code lives in the same view that is used to process photo uploading, so I reckon doing it asynchronously will speed up that process for the user.

I'm new to `celery` tasks, so can someone point out via an illustrative example how I can turn the aforementioned `bulk_create` task into a `celery` task? I've done research, and here's what I think I need to do:

1) Add `delay()` at the end of the `bulk_create` statement:

```
PhotoObjectSubscription.objects.bulk_create(fan_list).delay()
```

2) In `tasks.py`, add a new task to process the above:

```
@task
def bulk_create_notifications():
    PhotoObjectSubscription.objects.bulk_create(fan_list)
```

3) No need to add anything to `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` in `settings.py`, since the task is not a periodic task.

I'm probably not entirely correct, so please do help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `fans` (you might have to cast it to `list` if it is actually a `ValuesListQuerySet`) and all other things the task needs (e.g. `photo.id`) as an argument to the task:

```
@task
def bulk_create_notifications(fans, photo_id):
    fan_list = []
    for fan in fans:
        fan_list.append(PhotoObjectSubscription(viewer_id=fan, which_photo_id=photo_id, updated_at=time, seen=False, type_of_object='1'))
    PhotoObjectSubscription.objects.bulk_create(fan_list)
```

Then, you can asynchronously start the task via:

```
# call delay on the task and pass it the same params you would pass to the fnc itself
bulk_create_notifications.delay(fans)
```

Since the arguments need to be stored and communicated by your task queue (redis) you can only pass arguments that are serializable by the serializer you have set in your settings (probably JSON). That means you should stick to simple types s.a. strings, integers and you cannot pass model instances or lists thereof as parameters.

You could of course start even higher and just pass `user.id` and do all the db work in the task.

Comment: No. That was me misreading your code. I changed it in the answer already. You cannot pass model instances! It might work in your dev env when you have CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER setting at `True`, but not whwn the params are actually passed through the queue.

Comment: @HassanBaig Actually, `fans` in your code is a `ValuesListQuerySet` which you should cast to `list` before passing it to the task.

Comment: Got it. I'm going to try this and get back to you in a bit!

Comment: Question: in views.py, where I have `bulk_create_notifications.delay(fans)`, should I also add `from myapp/links import bulk_create_notifications` at the top of the file. Should I treat it like any other method?

Comment: @HassanBaig Yes, just like any other. Note that you can still call as a normal method. The name has to be known to the interpreter.  I like to keep my tasks in app level module named `tasks.py`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl could you please add a note that this code is working only with autocommit? with transactions it may generate errors (for django < 1.9 one should use django-transaction-hooks - integrated in django from 1.9)

Comment: @Jerzyk: can you also educate me about what you mean? I think you mean it only works in my particular scenario since I'm using `bulk_create` (which autocommits database changes). This wouldn't work with other transactions (would be great if you could provide an example of such transactions - better yet, just edit the answer, or add your own below).

Comment: @HassanBaig if you are using transactions (not autocommit) you may have encounter that celery task is being called from inside of transaction and celery task can start running *before* transaction commit will finish, in  such a case you will have data inconsistency, because celery task may read old data or celery task will be fast and update record before transaction commit and then every change made by task will be overwritten by commit
you should call celery task after transaction commit, django 1.9 introduced way to do this, for earlier versions one should use django-transaction-hooks